# criação de senha no padrão laravel

Tags: laravel, criptografia, senhas

Bom dia a todos!!
Como faço para criar uma senha no estilo das senhas criadas pelo laravel?
por razões muito particulares eu preciso usar a tabela de users do laravel, mas é minha aplicação paralela que vai criar esses novos usuários, porém, quero que o laravel também acesse esses usuários.
Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: A sua aplicação paralela também usa Laravel? Poderia falar mais sobre essas razões particulares e explicar melhor o seu contexto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O hashing das senhas no Laravel é configurado no `config/hashing.php` e, *por padrão*, está configurado para usar o algoritmo **bcrypt**.

Para criar uma senha usando a função de hash, você pode usar o seguinte:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

$senha = Hash::make('exemplo123');
```

Outra possibilidade, caso deseje usar o algoritmo bcrypt mesmo, é usar o seguinte helper do Laravel:

```
$senha = bcrypt('exemplo123');
```

Você pode consultar a [documentação do Laravel sobre hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing) para entender mais.

Comment: deu certo!! obrigado!